# Multiple join level with hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria, fetch

I am new to Hibernate and I would Like to know how this sort of things with Criteria :

I have three classes A, B and C.
the Class A has the association @OneToMany with class B. And Class B have the association @ManyToOne with class C.

I would like to have a request made with Criteria that retrive all the informations when I want an object from class A so that I can iterate through A.Bs and then access b.c

At the moment I have a query that retrieve only B :

```
session.createCriteria(A.class)
.add(Restrictions.idEq(aId))
.setFetchMode("B", FetchMode.JOIN)
.uniqueResult();
```

Thank you for your help

edit : 
I tried that :

```
session.createCriteria(A.class)
.add(Restrictions.idEq(aId))
.createCriteria("Bs")
.createCriteria("C")
.uniqueResult();
```

But have that ended with this error :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution :

```
session.createCriteria(A.class)
.add(Restrictions.idEq(aId))
.setFetchMode("Bs", FetchMode.JOIN)
.setFetchMode("Bs.c", FetchMode.JOIN)
.uniqueResult();
```

Where 'Bs' is the attribute of A containing the @OneToMany association and 'c' is the attribute of B container the @ManyToOne association.